# Haskell - creation of a monad

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand the rules of how to create a monad. As far as I understand, it depends on the data types that I want to use and that a monad has to fulfill three laws:

```
1. m >>= return = m
2. return x >>= f = f x
3. (m >>= f) >>= g = m >>= (\x-> f x) >>= g
```

Okay. So for a monad `Maybe` I have the last 2 lines. For what does "`x`" stands in the third line. If should be a function, should it not?

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
instance Monad Maybe where
  (Just x) >>= f = f x
  Nothing >>= _ = Nothing
  _ >>= x = x  

 fail _ = Nothing
```

(I am unable to find now the source of this definition, but I found it somewhere)

I found another version as well - why do I need the line with "fail"?

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
instance Monad Maube where
  return x = Just x

  Just x >>= f = f x
  Nothing >>= f = Nothing

  fail _ = Nothing
```

(source: http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads)

Comment: Can you provide the source where you've got these definitions from?

Comment: `_ >>= x = x` is just wrong. `>>=` has type `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, so this definition ignores the `m a` value (which we know is a `Just`, but it doesn't matter here), and tries to return the `a -> m b` value as if it were an `m b`.

Comment: Indeed. _Where exactly_ did you find that definition with `_ >>= x = x`? At least it's neither in the online version of LYAH nor in my print one. And, well, it shouldn't be, wrong-wise.

Comment: @chepner I don't think it matters. That line of code is just a dead code and will never be reachable.

Comment: @Sibi It still has to type-check, or the compiler will reject it.

Comment: @amalloy Ah yes. I didn't notice that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to read through [this chapter of 'Learn you a Haskell'](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#the-monad-type-class), it provides some examples that should help you clarify what a monad is.

Going back to your question about `x`, it is not a function, but it's the value contained in `Just`. `Maybe a` is a type with two different constructors: `Nothing`, which means it's not holding any value, and `Just a`, which means it's holding a value of type `a`.

Let's look at the signature of `>>=`. It is `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, which means it takes a monad `m a`, a function `(a -> m b)` and returns a monad `m b`. Note that you have the same monad `m` but possibly a different value of it's type parameter (from `a` to `b`).

For `Maybe a` we need to handle two cases: when we have a value (`Just a`) or when we don't have a value (`Nothing`). `>>=` for `Maybe` is implemented such that applies `f` to the value there is a value, otherwise it simply propagates `Nothing`. In your example you also have `_ >>= x = x`, but that's not needed since you already exhaustively matched all the possible patterns.